# plot one point in highchart shiny r

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

It is possible to plot an highchart with only one element in the series?
i.e.

```
hc<-highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = a) %>%
  hc_add_serie(data = b, type = "scatter")
```

where a=1 and b=2?

When I try to do this, the highchart windows is opened but no chart is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed [here](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/65), basically is the way tje data is transformed from R to javascript via `jsonlite` package.

The solution is give the `b` value as a list `list(b)`:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2

highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = a) %>%
  hc_add_serie(data = list(b), type = "scatter")
```